# robots.txt on domain instead of subdomain?

Tags: robots.txt

I am researching this. I need suggestions.

I have a domain that I own. It is pointed to a subdomain that is my business that I do not own. The subdomain's robots.txt file controls the images I am trying to list in the Microsoft Shopping. But Microsoft Shopping wants to crawl the image URLs. The robots.txt will not allow this.

I need to use resources to have my domain carry its own robots.txt file while integrated with the subdomain. I need to avoid redirects for Microsoft.

TIA

Comment: Every domain (sub- or not) will need its own robots.txt.

Comment: The shop with the subdomain I do not control that. I guess my question is what do I need to do resource wise to set up my domain so I can add my own robots.txt and yet have full functionality with the subdomain and shop? I am very much unfamiliar with the resources. TIA

Comment: Then you are out of luck.

Comment: Could I mirror the subdomain?